# EscaparateTerminalesComponent > ngOnInit > should be defined TypeError: this.param1.indexOf is not a function

Tags: typescript, angular8

Estaba desarrollando una App en Angular 8 con TypesScript, en la que estaba implementando la parte de testing de uno de los componentes.

Acabo de empezar por motivos laborales en el mundo JavaScript, y sus frameworks, ya que anteriormente programaba en Android con Java/kotlin.

Con respecto al código del archivo spec.ts, es el siguiente:

```
describe('ngOnInit', () => {
     it('should be defined', () => {
     const spy = spyOn(component, 'ngOnInit').and.callThrough();
            
            component.ngOnInit();
            expect(component.ngOnInit).toBeDefined();
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();

     });
  });
```

Y con respecto al componente en si es el siguiente:

```
ngOnInit() {
    // console.log('funciona la ultima  parte', this.productSpecification, this.slide, this.charact);
    this.pageDefaultValueControlService.pageDefaultValuesController().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(res => {
        this.defaultValues = res;
        this.defaultRatesValues = this.pageDefaultValueControlService.packRates(res.packConvergente);
        this.getCurrentData();
    });

    // this.pageDefaultValueControlService.pageDefaultRatesController().pipe(take(1)).subscribe( res => {
    //     this.defaultRatesValues = res;
    // });
    // this.modelo = this.route.snapshot.children[0].paramMap.get('modeloDispositivo');
    this.modelo = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('modeloDispositivo');

    // this.modelo = 'ALCATEL-1066';
    // this.modelo = 'SAMSUNG-GALAXY-TAB-S5E-10-5-4G';
    this.modelo = this.modelo ? this.modelo.split('-').join(' ') : null;
    // this.datosPredef = this.datosCintillosService.getDatosCintillo(this.movil.deviceSpecification.id);
    this.title.setTitle(this.modelo);
    this.param1 = this.router.url;
    this.estoyEnSerCliente = this.param1.indexOf('cliente') ;// miro si estoy en cartera o en captacion
    this.currentDataService.getCurrentData().subscribe(data => {
      this.loadingComponents = data.loadingComponents;
      this.setValueCCC(data.shoppingCart);
    });
    this.actualizarCarga(true);
    this.termData = new TerminalesData(this.moduleData);
    // console.log('CONTRIBUCIONES', this.termData);
    this.obtenerEscaps(this.termData);
    // this.getCurrentData();
    const _t = this;
    document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      _t.cerrarPincharFuera(e);
    }, false);
    this.tituloPrimero = this.termData.orderComponents[0];
    // console.log('parametro', this.param1);

    // this.sacarModelUrl(this.param1);

  }
```

El error que me vierte Karma, es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si teneís idea de por donde van los tiros, muchas gracias de ante mano!

Answer (score 1):

En un método ngOnInit tienes las líneas

```
this.param1 = this.router.url;
this.estoyEnSerCliente = this.param1.indexOf('cliente') ;
```

Parece ser que this.param1 no es lo que esperas, no sé si has "mockeado" el router a inyectar y si le has definido la URL correctamente, pero es lo que te está fallando.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario, pero he empezado a desarrollar con Angular hace unos meses y estoy un poco verde, me podrías poner un ejemplo??

Comment: Echa un vistazo a esto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40187305/1919228

Comment: Estás ejecutando el método ngOnInit, que hace uso del router para obtener datos. Tienes que darle, por tanto, unos valores válidos para que no te falle. Puesto que la propiedad `this.router` es recibida en el constructor, deberás asegurarte al instanciar tu componente de que exista router y router.url tenga un valor correcto